# DoubleValue and FloatValue Implementation

Tags: apache-flink

I am looking at the Apache Flink source code and reading the `flink-core` module. I don’t understand why `DoubleValue` and `FloatValue` do not implement the `NormalizableKey` interface, but `IntValue` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NormalizableKey` interface defines methods to generate a fixed-length binary prefix key, i.e., a byte sequence. The purpose of the prefix key is to directly compare values on the raw bytes without expensive object deserialization.

Such a fixed-length prefix key is trivial to obtain for integer values such as `Integer`, `Long`, and, `Short`. However, the binary representation of floating point values (`Float`, `Double`) differs from integer values and consists of three parts: an exponent, a fraction, and a sign bit. Due to this representation floating point values can cover a huge value range (at the cost of precision). A binary representation for floating point values that can be compared without deserialization is not as easy to define as for integer values. Moreover, the most common use cases for normalized keys are grouping or joining. Since these operations require object equality, they are less common for floating point values.

That is why `FloatValue` and `DoubleValue` do not implement the `NormalizableKey` interface. Normalized keys would be beneficial for sorting data on floating point values.

Comment: Thanks for the details!